# What Parameters ConsoleApplication Sends to Main()

Tags: c#, parameters, console-application, program-entry-point, windows

I try to convert the `class Program`  of `Console Application` to a regular class, in order to integrate it in a `Windows Application` project.

I would like to invoke the `void Main` method. What parameters should I send it?

**In Class Program:**

`public static void Main(string[] args)`

**In another class :**

`Program.Main(?);`

Comment: you can remove string[] args parameters from main method If you are not using it

Comment: You _don't_ have to you use `string[] args` as a parameter by the way..

Comment: @SonerGönül, but class Program uses them, so I need them

Comment: @Neel, But I do use them. Any ideas?

Comment: I would not attempt to call `Program.Main()`. It's code for a console application. You'll need different code in your GUI app. And then you claim that the command line arguments are used, but you want us to tell you what arguments to pass. Do you know what your own code is actually doing?

Comment: this question sounds like: `I have a method Sum(int x, int y) what should I pass to my function ?`

Comment: why you want to call Program.Main()?

Comment: @Neel, I want to integrate a the program class to a win-app.

Comment: Calling `Program.Main()` will not achieve that.

Comment: I agree with the others, I don't see the problem. Anyway, the args string array contains the args given to the assembly when launched. For instance "myApp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3" you'll end with 4 arguments. The first one is the called executable then arg1, arg2 and arg3. (a size 4 array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to pass to `Program.Main()` the arguments that were passed when the Windows application executable is started, you could do:

```
Program.Main(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
```

However, it's a bad idea to keep your method as 'Main', because you'll end up with 2 main methods in your Windows application (one created by Visual Studio, and yours).

Comment: That's sound like what I was looking for! Re your comment about the two mains: if it is a dll that invoked on some event and causes the Program.Main to be invoked - does it still problematic?

Comment: Well, if your 'Main' function is in a dll, it might be ok (never tried) but in any case, 'Main' should be reserved for an application entry-point, as the run-time will look for a static method with that name when starting your application. It's possible to use the /main' option when compiling the application to specify which class contains the Main, but I would not recommend it. Also, Main should typically contain little code, most of the time it will call some other method in one of the application's classes to do the actual work...

Comment: so in case of a dll, just renaming the Main is the complete solution?

Comment: Yes, or even if you keep it within the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, I don't see the problem...

Anyway, the args string array contains the args given to the assembly when launched. For instance :

```
"C:\myApp.exe arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

The first one is the called executable then arg1, arg2 and arg3. (a size 4 array).

If you want to call Main like through the CLI just do something like :

```
Programe.Main(new string[] {String.Empty, "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"});
```

After it will always depend on the way you use the parameters within your CLI application.

A good idea would be to refactor your application and use Program.Main as the CLI entry point but not the "application" entry point. So you'll be able to use several entry point to the same logic.